# base_pose_ground_truth type?

Tags: ros, gazebo, subscribe, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ros users. I am trying to subscribe to base_pose_ground_truth topic but I can't.
My code is this:

```
nav_msgs::base_pose_ground_truth subs;
 double variable1;
 double variable2;
 void velsubcallback(const nav_msgs::base_pose_ground_truth& msg)
   {
  
  variable1=msg.twist.twist.linear.x;
    variable2=msg.twist.twist.angular.z;
     lectura_ros.linear=variable1;
     lectura_ros.angular=variable2;
     ROS_INFO("variable %f",lectura_ros.linear);
```

How can i subscribe on that topic?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213858/base_pose_ground_truth-type?/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to subscribe to a topic of (message) type `nav_msgs::base_pose_ground_truth`. As far as I know, the (named) topic `/base_pose_ground_truth` is actually of type `nav_msgs::Odometry` (you can check with `rostopic info /base_pose_ground_truth` when the node is running).

So replace `nav_msgs::base_pose_ground_truth` with `nav_msgs::Odometry`. And don't forget to properly initialize your Subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-07-16**:
Yes! That´s the way!
base_pose_ground_truth topic give me the velocities relative to world coordinates and I want relative to base_link coordinates. is there any way to make a transform between these coordinates?

Thanks!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-17**:
Why don't you use the 'odom' topic then?
Otherwise, I think you have to transform it yourself, which is straightforward. You know the global pose and velocity. So just rotate the (translational) velocity vector to compensate for the current rotation. The rotational velocity is constant (as it is 2D)

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-07-17**:
Thanks again @mig I can't subsbribe to odom topic because I must have gaussian noise and in odom topic there isn't.
how can I rotate de axes? because if I rotate linear velocity in X an angle equal to angular velocity in Z it should work. But how can I do that? what is the command in C++?

Thanks!!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-17**:
Can you accept the answer, if it solved the original question (by clicking on the checkmark)? Thx.
I don't know a specific command. I would have coded that myself.
Or try [transformVector](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html#a6c3cd856bf584f98db6f0f295c2d9f52)